# How to build list with defvar in emacs

Tags: list, emacs, lisp, elisp

I used code like this：

```
(defvar my-defvar "test")
(completing-read "input: " '("1" "2" my-defvar))
```

Then <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-region`.
I got "1", "2", `my-defvar` in minibuffer.

My question is how to convert `my-defvar` to string in a list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Lisp, the `´`-symbol will *quote* the rest of the expression. This means that the value will be the expression exactly as it is written, function calls are not evaluated, variables are not replaced with it's value etc.

The most straight-forward way is to use the function `list` that creates a list of elements, after evaluating it's arguments, for example:

```
(completing-read "input: " (list "1" "2" my-defvar))
```

Of course, you could also use the *backquote* syntax, as suggested in another answer. This allows you to quote a complex expression but *unquote* (i.e. evaluate) parts of it. However, in this simple case I don't think it's the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 6):

`my-defvar` isn't being evaluated as a variable, it's being interpreted as a symbol.

See [Emacs Lisp: evaluate variable in alist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664202/emacs-lisp-evaluate-variable-in-alist).

So:

```
(defvar my-defvar "test")
(completing-read "input: " `("1" "2" ,my-defvar))
```

should work.

**Update:** A more appropriate solution is given in @Lindydancer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9699195/772653), but I leave this here for reference.

Comment: It's not being evaluated as a *string literal* (as quotes aren't used), instead it's being interpreted as a *symbol*.

Comment: I've now corrected this, although I think your answer is more appropriate.