# Emacs lisp evaluate variable in alist

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

This is a follow-up question to [Emacs Lisp: evaluate variable in alist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664202/emacs-lisp-evaluate-variable-in-alist)..
I am trying to set `default-frame-alist` in my `.emacs` file. Consider, e.g.

```lisp
(setq default-frame-alist
      '((auto-lower . nil)
        (auto-raise . nil)
        (height . 41)
        (width . 80)
        (top . 1)
        (left . 1)))
```

(I have omitted some values) This works fine.. Suppose now I want set the `height` according to another variable..Say, I stored the integer value 50 in the variable `my-height`.. How can I set `height` to the value of `my-height` ? I have tried

- `(height . my-height)`
- ``(height . ,my-height)`

but neither works.. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) the whole form:

```
(setq default-frame-alist
      `((auto-lower . nil)
        (auto-raise . nil)
        (height . ,my-height)
        (width . 80)
        (top . 1)
        (left . 1)))
```